# Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() not looking in the correct path

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I'm reading an embedded xml file using

C#:

```
var AssemblyRef = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(AssemblyRef.GetManifestResourceStream("Text.xml"));
```

It has been working for some time, but starting throwing errors. I traced the path that it is looking for and it is looking for the dll in the root of the bin folder and not in the Debug or release folder.

Once it is published this is fine, but for local development I cannot get my one feature to work.

I have it set to Debug when compiling. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the call to this and everything is fine.

```
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().AssemblyRef.GetManifestResourceStream("Text.xml"));
```

Making the call one statement made it work. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

- Changed Assembly Name OR
- Changed namespace OR
- Moved the resource to a folder in the project

Comment: What is faster: reading a xml file with IO or as an embedded resource?

Comment: Assmebly! since it has already been loaded onto memory. So which one was the problem? Did my comment help?

Comment: I've checked them all. Non of them have changed. It is like it doesn't not it is not a 'published' source and is not looking in bin/debug. But at one time is was. The code base for this have not changed.